# Не получается получить JSON данные в Angular от REST - сервиса

Tags: json, angularjs, rest

Есть rest сервис на symfony, возвращающий данные в json: 
`[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "name",
    "content": "text",
    "isapproved": true
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "nsdfgdsgdgame",
    "content": "textdsagjhglkdsg",
    "isapproved": true
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "title": "name",
    "content": "text",
    "date": "2017-08-11T19:52:38+03:00",
    "isapproved": true
  }
]`
Проблема в том, что не получается получить данные в angular, при обращении по url-адресу. При обращении к json-файлу, содержащему те же данные,такой проблемы нет(данные парсятся и выводятся, как положено).
Собственно, код страницы:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="newsApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js">
  </script>
  <script>
    newsApp = angular.module('newsApp', []);

    newsApp.controller('NewsController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
        $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:8000/news"
        }).then(function(response){
            $scope.records = response.data;
        });
    }]);
  </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="NewsController">
  <div ng-repeat="record in records">
    <h4>{{record.id}}</h4>
      <p>{{record.title}}</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Было бы неплохо, для начала узнать, какая ошибка выводится в консоли браузера.

Comment: В консоли пусто

Comment: А если обратиться к сервису через  браузерную строку или программу для проверки запросов, он точно вернет JSON? И как вариант выведите в консоль response.data, может быть так станет яснее

Comment: Да, возвращает json.  console.log('response.data'); ничего не дает, консоль молчит. При .error(function(response){
            console.log('error');
         }) выводит error.

Comment: а попробуйте вот так: $http.get("http://localhost:8000/news").then(x=> console.log(x));